# Showing JDK modules' dependencies

Tags: java, java-module

There is possible to see all JDK modules via `java --list-modules` but whether it's possible to see JDK modules dependency tree in a way of `mvn dependency:tree` command?

```
[INFO] [dependency:tree]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:maven-plugin:2.0-alpha-5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |        \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.0)
[INFO] \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.0-alpha-8:compile
[INFO]    \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO]       \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.0:compile
```

Comment: Nothing public and official that I have seen, but the [module-graph built for JDK used `ClassAnalyzer` tool.](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/doc/jdk-modularization.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jdeps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jdeps.htm#JSWOR690), like:

```
jdeps --list-deps c:\path\to\your\jar
```

This will list the module dependences and also the package names of JDK internal APIs (if referenced).

For example:

```
jdeps --list-deps c:\jdk-11.0.2\lib\jrt-fs.jar
```

outputs:

```java
Warning: split package: jdk.internal.jimage jrt:/java.base c:\jdk-11.0.2\lib\jrt-fs.jar
Warning: split package: jdk.internal.jimage.decompressor jrt:/java.base c:\jdk-11.0.2\lib\jrt-fs.jar
Warning: split package: jdk.internal.jrtfs jrt:/java.base c:\jdk-11.0.2\lib\jrt-fs.jar
   java.base
```

Comment: I need to have a list of modules in JDK with dependencies. Prefferable in a tree forms. Is it possible?

Comment: So, you need to print modules, and per each module, print its dependencies..? like mixing modules and dependencies? I'm not sure it's possible to be outputted as a tree.. but maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Module API to generate a graph. An example would be using the following code, like in JShell

```java
import java.lang.module.*

ModuleFinder.ofSystem()
    .findAll()
    .stream()
    .map(ModuleReference::descriptor())
    .forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.name() + "\n\t" + 
                  Arrays.deepToString(x.requires().toArray())))
```